# Is there a way to get an r-squared value for nonlinear regression?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, statistics

I managed to optimize a line in order to get a line of best fit using curve_fit, but I can't seem to get the R squared value the way I can for linear regression, this is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from scipy.optimize import *
from scipy.integrate import *
from scipy.interpolate import * 
df=pd.read_csv('F:/Data32.csv')
df2=df['Temperature']
df3=df['CO2-Rh']
def f(x,a,b,c) :
   return a*np.exp(b*x)+c
params, extras = curve_fit(f, df2, df3)
print('a=%g,b=%g, c=%g' %(params[0],df2[1],df3[2]))
plt.plot(df2,df3,'o')
plt.plot(df2,f(df2,params[0],params[1],params[2]))
plt.legend(['data','fit'],loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Comment: R^2 isn't a valid goodness-of-fit statistic for nonlinear regression. Indeed, googling your title will result in plenty of hits explaining exactly why.

Comment: what can I use instead @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: That is a huge topic. To be fair, plenty of people just go ahead and use R^2. Lies, damn lies, and statistics and all that... Personally, if you are going to do that, I would just use mean-squared error with the caveat that it doesn't let you compare across models. Or rather, it doesn't let you compare how well your model fits this data to how well another model fits *another* set of data. But if you just want to compare models to the same data, MSE is fine.

Comment: Honestly, if you are curious, I would take this over to [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)